# Video is not playing inside the browser

Tags: html, css, video, mp4, webm

The video I have embedded is neither appearing nor playing. I am unsure what's causing this problem. The code is as follows:

As for my file path, I have the video in web and mp4 format in a folder called **media** inside my HTML main folder.

The console outputs this:

> [Error] Not allowed to load local resource:
> file:///Users/kudos/Desktop/html2/AH.mp4 [Error] Not allowed to load
> local resource: file:///Users/kudos/Desktop/html2/AH.webm

```
<video width="320" height="240">
 <source src="AH.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="AH.webm" type="video/webm">

</video>
```

I've tried checking the encoding, and clearing my browser cache (I'm using safari), yet no luck. Any help appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: so check in your browser console if you have some 404 errors

Comment: @Sfili_81 it says its not allowed to open the resource.

Comment: Post your error in the question, so we can help you to find a solution

Comment: I have now posted the console errors

Comment: Where are you serving from? Is this an html file on your local machine, or is it on some remote server?

Comment: @A Haworth this is on my machine. just dragged into a browser

Comment: @Kudos If using `src="AH.mp4"` then keep the video files and the HTML file **together** in same place/folder (**no sub-folders**). PS: Browser's have a security limit about running any random scripts/resources from the hard drive. The trick for testing from HDD is to not involve any sub folders in your URLs (or file paths). also if failing in Safari browser, then try opening your HTML with the Chrome browser. PPS: For local testing you need to use a local server. Try [XAMPP for Mac](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) for easy install and then move on to your HTML code testing.

Comment: @VC.One thanks for the tips. I'm a beginner developer so I'm still trying to figure out how these things work. I'll try that.

Comment: @Kudos The basic fix is to not use any folders in the paths. Just use a file name (so then also keep everything together in one folder, _eg:_ html is listed next to the mp4 in file listing). As a web developer then installing XAMPP is definitely a good idea (you get PHP included, always useful that one for later interesting projects). It will install on your had drive but a certain folder will be treated as if it was a web space by your browsers (so you put your files and folders in there for testing) and browsers see that HDD folder's "web address" as `https://127.0.0.1`... PS Chrome is best.

Comment: @VC.One it works now after some right clicking on show controls. thanks for the help

Comment: @Kudos Okay I'm not going to say "You don't understand the error" but the fact is.. You don't understand the error. Doing a Right-click on a video object to set "show controls" does not fix:  **(1)** _"The video is not appearing"_ from your Question's first line. **(2)** _"I have the video in a folder called **media**"_ but the shown path is `src="AH.mp4"` instead of `src="media/AH.mp4"`. **(3)** Not obvious how _show controls_ fixes _"Not allowed to load local resource: `file:///Users/...`"_ ... You did something in the middle that fixed it (along with showing controls). Maybe post an Answer.

Comment: @VC.One apologies for the late reply. I fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

You are running into this issued because the browser does not allow to load local resources because of the security. The browser need an url. The problem is because the browser doesn't allow loading local resources.

One way to solve this issue, go to file location and start a Python Server from there. e.g running:

```
python3 -m http.server 9000
```

Then prepend `http://localhost:9000` in your src, making it something like this.

```
<video width="320" height="240">
 <source src="http://localhost:9000/media/AH.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="http://localhost:9000/media/AH.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

If your html file is placed in that folder and is named index.html, you can navigate to `http://localhost:9000` and then your page should open up.

Comment: Installing a local server is the best solution for the errors (since this is testing from hard drive).